# what's the difference between to and and?

Tags: meaning

> a hidden wall panel moved aside to reveal what could best be described as an ancient alien library

> a hidden wall panel moved aside and revealed what could best be described as an ancient alien library

The first one is the original sentence and the latter is what I made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case there is not much difference in meaning. The use of "to" emphasizes the cause-and-effect sequence, while the use of "and" only indicates a sequence in time.

> - I want you to lift your head to improve your posture. (Lifting the head will cause the better posture)
> - I want you to lift your head and improve your posture. (Lifting the head and better posture may be quite separate, but you should do both.)

> - You should take this pill to get a good night's sleep. (The pill will provide the sleep.)
> - You should take this pill and get a good night's sleep. (The pill and the sleepmay be quite unrelated.)